# In getAsObject arg2 is passed as null

Tags: java, jsf-2, converters

I am using JSF2.0 with tomcat 7 and I have couple of selectOneListBox defined in my page. These are initially assigned to empty ArrayLists as below

```
<h:selectOneListbox value="#{memberBean.currentAvailable}" converter="memberConverter" 
                            size="10" style="width:150px;">
            <f:selectItems value="#{memberBean.availableMembers}" var="member"
                             itemValue="#{member}" itemLabel="#   {member.fname} #{member.lname}" />
        </h:selectOneListbox>
        <h:panelGrid>
            <a4j:commandButton value="Add" render="groupMessage_Page" listner="#{memberBean.moveAvaiableMember}"/>
            <a4j:commandButton value="Remove" render="groupMessage_Page" listner="#{memberBean.moveSelectedMember}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:selectOneListbox value="#{memberBean.currentSelected}" converter="memberConverter"
                            size="10" style="width:150px;">
            <f:selectItems value="#{memberBean.selectedMembers}" var="member"
                        itemValue="#{member}" itemLabel="#{member.fname} #{member.lname}" />
        </h:selectOneListbox>
```

In case of any event on the page the getAsObject is called of the converter defined as the String arg2 is null. I am wondering that is it normal that the method is called with a null argument or am I initializing something in wrong manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did not happen in JSF 1.x, but this will happen in JSF 2.x. This is among others done in order to properly support bean valiation such as `@NotNull`. Before passing tho the bean validation, JSF has by specification first to convert it. You just have to add a nullcheck and return `null` or something else.

The following context parameter in `web.xml` will disable it, but this way you won't be able to use `@NotNull` anymore:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the reply. The nullcheck does not solve the issue as I tried with nullCheck. In this case I believe the request response cycle is not completed and the commandButton does not complete it action. If I create the SelectItems in the bean and use it for h:selectItems then everything goes fine and there is no null in the getAsObject.

Comment: Huh? How are you nullchecking it then? It should be as simple as `if (value == null) return null;`.

Comment: Putting that <context-param> in the web.xml also doesnot help. I am still getting the arg2=null

Comment: Putting the null check does solve the problem. But <context-param> seems to have no effect. Thanks BalusC.